# Fragment Layout keeps jumping up & down when main activity thread active

Tags: java, multithreading, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

A very strange problem. I've created a main layout with a fixed toolbar and inserted a fragment placeholder right under it. The layout holds together and works perfectly, complete with screen rotation, soft-keyboard resizing, input, etc.

[image]

*The main layout structure:*

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"...

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"...

        <include layout="@layout/global_header"/>

        <fragment 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*The code:*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ...
    } else {
        Fragment newFragment = new fragment_code();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_frame, newFragment).commit();
    }


    final TextView g_header_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.global_header_date);
    final TextView g_header_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.global_header_time);

    Thread headerClock = new Thread() {
        SimpleDateFormat header_date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat header_time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Date dt = new Date();
                            g_header_date.setText("Date:  " + header_date.format(dt));
                            g_header_time.setText("Time:  " + (header_time.format(dt)).replace(".", ""));
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    };

    //headerClock.start();

}

public static class fragment_code extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

But if I uncomment the **headerClock.start(),** the fragment *(pink area)* keeps jumping up and down to the tick of the timer.

The toolbar is part of the main layout, but shares a vertical linear layout with the fragment so that they will fill the screen.

Might anyone have any idea?

***EDIT:** Opening and closing the soft-keyboard stops the jumping.*

Answer (score 0):

hi @iSofia the issue might be that you set `wrap_content` has height to toolbar and fragment is placed below it. So when ever time changes the height of the toolbar should be varying by a small margin to accompany varied height of numbers and so fragment is pushed up and down.

**The Possible solution** is to set a **fixed height** to your Global Header/Tool bar so that it don't changes its height for every time change.

Hope it helps you.